# NVIDIA G-SYNC 'unvalidated' for officially validated monitor?

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, edid

I'm looking at a green NVIDIA G-SYNC sticker on the bezel of my monitor, yet the NVIDIA driver tells me 'G-SYNC Unvalidated', and I can only get G-SYNC working when I specifically set 'Allow G-SYNC on monitor not validated as G-SYNC Compatible'. Why?

I've read this article: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=gsync-compatible-linux&num=1 which states that the whitelist for validated monitors is the same one used for Windows. It includes a link to the official NVIDIA list of supported monitors: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/products/g-sync-monitors/specs/

My monitor is listed, it's a Dell AW3420DW (it also show this in `nvidia-settings`), and I'm driving it through the DisplayPort, per the requirement. The graphics card is a RTX 3090 FE. I've been looking at the EDID of the monitor, that looks OK too. So I'm puzzled as to why it insists my display is 'unvalidated'... Any ideas?

Comment: Please ask here as well https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148